# Why can't I assign a U to a Partial<T> when T extends U?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

For example:

```js
interface U {
  u: boolean;
}

const f = <T extends U>() => {
  const t: Partial<T> = {u: true};
};
```

I get the following error:

```
Type '{ u: true; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'.ts(2322)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=31#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKrIN4ChnIK4BcyARgPakA2EcIA3FgL5ZYKkgDOYyMyAvMgB4AKsggAPSCAAm7NAD4AFAEo%20czDmSsOXMEQAKcKGGBwKwtfwyFkYKHggN6joA)

Is there a way to fix this without casting to any?

Comment: Technically, the answer to *"Is there a way to fix this without casting to any?"* is "Yes: `const t: Partial<T> = {u: true} as Partial<T>;`" But that's not really helpful... ;-) Would it be accurate to reword that as *"...without using a type assertion?"* ?

Comment: this works `const t = { u: true } as Partial<T>;`

Answer (score 1):

The issue, that TypeScript complains about is the following:

`Type '{ u: true; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'.ts(2322)`

your function `f` could be called with:

```js
f<{ u: boolean, v: boolean }>(); // ok since U is "implemented" but not "v"
```

this opens the option, that your generic and your provided concrete implementation of an object inside the function `{ u: true }` could differ.

The TypeScript compiler doesn't enforce you to define the same type as it extends, you are still able to specify a more specific implementation of U as long as U is fully provided (in this case the boolean flag `u`).

### A few possible solutions are:

#### Use Type-Cast (as used before):

```js
interface U {
  u: boolean;
}

const f = <T extends U>() => {
  const t: Partial<T> = {u: true} as Partial<T>;
};

f<U>();
```

*Downside:* `{ u: true }` could well be replaced with: `{ v: true }` which can cause issues with undefined later on in your code.

#### Try to re-phrase your function

To tell the compiler to exactly use type `U`, you could, if possible, try to re-phrase the function and move the constant `t` as a function parameter.

```js
interface U {
  u: boolean;
}

const f = <T>(u: T) => {
  const t: Partial<T> = u;
};

f<{ u: boolean }>({ u: true });
```

#### Consider if generics are relevant

Your function requires a generic type but your function body assigns a concrete type which causes the trouble here. You could consider if generics are relevant there. A generic free alternative would be:

```
interface U {
  u: boolean;
}

const f = () => {
  const t: Partial<U> = {u: true};
};

f();
```