# How do I express that S must have a property "dirty" of type boolean?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I tried to ask this earlier generically ([Why can't I assign a U to a Partial<T> when T extends U?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60149705/why-cant-i-assign-a-u-to-a-partialt-when-t-extends-u)) and I think I now understand why `S extends {dirty: boolean}` is incorrect (S could be `{dirty: false}`, but most of the suggestions were to rewrite the function in some way. So, how do I rewrite this function so that it has proper type checking and doesn't require a cast?

```js
import {ActionCreatorWithPreparedPayload} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {assert, pick} from '@helpmedo/util';
import {State, ThunkAction} from '@helpmedo/state';

export const createAsyncUpdateAction = <Arg, S extends {dirty: boolean}, P>(
  updateAction: ActionCreatorWithPreparedPayload<[Arg, Partial<S>], P>,
  selector: (state: State, arg: Arg) => S,
) => (
  arg: Arg,
  update: Partial<S>,
  asyncUpdate: () => Promise<unknown>,
): ThunkAction<unknown> => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const state = selector(getState(), arg);
  assert(!state.dirty, 'Attempt to modify dirty state');
  const save = pick(state, Object.keys(update));
  dispatch(updateAction(arg, {...update, dirty: true}));
  try {
    const result = await asyncUpdate();
    dispatch(updateAction(arg, {dirty: false} /* as Partial<S> */));
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(updateAction(arg, {...save, dirty: false}));
    throw err;
  }
};
```

The existing error is `Argument of type '{ dirty: false; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<S>'.ts(2345)` on the line with the commented out cast.

Comment: I would suggest you go through this link https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27473

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `S extends { dirty: boolean }` you are doing exactly what you're asking for in the question – you're declaring a type `S` which must have a `dirty` property.

When you declare a type as `Partial<S>`, you're saying that all the properties of `S` are optional. Therefore even the `dirty` property is.

Just getting rid of the partiality of S in `updateAction` like `updateAction: ActionCreatorWithPreparedPayload<[Arg, S], P>` and that should solve your problems

Answer (score 0):

you are doing `S extends { dirty: boolean }` correctly. just replace `Partial<S>` with `S` should fix as [SquattingSlavInTracksuit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60211780/7208274) explained.